# Output integer as phone number format in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to show show this as a formatted phone number like: `xxx-xxx-xxxx` instead of just a number string like it currently is ..any help would be great!

```
<% if @post.phone.present? %>
    <h4>Phone: <small> <%= @post.phone %><br></h4>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [number_to_phone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone) helper, like this:

```
<% if @post.phone.present? %>
   <h4>Phone: <small> <%= number_to_phone @post.phone %><br></h4>
<% end %>
```

By default, it formats the phone number as xxx-xxx-xxxx :

```
2.1.1 :009 > number_to_phone(1235551234)  
 => "123-555-1234" 
2.1.1 :010 > number_to_phone("1235551234")  
 => "123-555-1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `phone` gem. https://github.com/carr/phone

```
pn = Phoner::Phone.parse('+385915125486')
pn.to_s # => "+385915125486"
pn.format("%A/%f-%l") # => "091/512-5486"
pn.format("+ %c (%a) %n") # => "+ 385 (91) 5125486"
pn.format(:europe) # => "+385 (0) 91 512 5486"
pn.format(:us) # => "(234) 123-4567"
pn.format(:default_with_extension) # => "+3851234567x143"
```

Comment: Haven't tried this method but seemed easier to user number_to_phone